# How to pass json data in from model to controller in codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter

I am trying to pass data from model to controller in order to pass it through json to ajax page, I don't the correct way of doing, so far I have tried the following codes.

In my contoller;

```
 public function grid_view_ajax_function()
        {       
            $contacts_details="";
            $this->load->model('contact_model');
            $contacts_details= $this->contact_model->get_all_contacts();

            $data['id']                =$contacts_details->contact_id; /getting error  here
            $data['first_name']        =$contacts_details->first_name; /"
            $data['last_name']         =$contacts_details->last_name; /"
            $data['title']             =$contacts_details->title; /" 
            $data['city']              =$contacts_details->city; /"
            $data['country']           =$contacts_details->country_id;/"
            $data['city']              =$contacts_details->city;/"
            $data['contact_mobile']    =$contacts_details->contact_mobile;
            $data['unique_id']         =$contacts_details->unique_id;

            echo json_encode(array('id'=>$data['id'],'first_name'=>$data['first_name'],'last_name'=>$data['last_name'],'title'=>$data['title'],'city'=>$data['city'],'coutry'=>$data['contact_mobile'],'unique_id'=>$data['unique_id'] ));

        }
```

My model

```
public function get_all_contacts() {
        $this->db->select("c.id contact_id, c.salutation salutation, c.honorfic honorfic, c.first_name first_name, c.middle_name middle_name, c.last_name last_name, c.email_primary email_primary, c.email_secondry email_secondry, c.contact_mobile contact_mobile, c.contact_home contact_home, DATE_FORMAT(c.dob, '%e %M %Y') dob, c.image image, c.marital_status marital_status, c.spouse_name spouse_name, c.title title, c.email_work email_work, c.contact_work contact_work, c.assistant_name assistant_name, c.assistant_email assistant_email, c.address address, c.city city, c.state state, c.country_id country_id, c.postbox postbox, c.biography biography, c.created_by created_by, c.modified_by modified_by, c.created_on created_on, c.modified_on modified_on", false);
        $this->db->from("contact c");
        $this->db->where("c.flag_delete", '0');     
        $obj_result  = $this->db->get();
        $row         = $obj_result->result_array(); 


        return $row;
    }
```

I am getting the error  "Trying to get property of non-object" 
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$obj_result->result_array()` to `$obj_result->result()` and Try

```
         $contacts_details_list= $this->contact_model->get_all_contacts();
         $result = array();
         foreach($contacts_details_list as $contacts_details) {
            $data = array();
            $data['id']                =$contacts_details->contact_id; /getting error  here
            $data['first_name']        =$contacts_details->first_name; /"
            $data['last_name']         =$contacts_details->last_name; /"
            $data['title']             =$contacts_details->title; /" 
            $data['city']              =$contacts_details->city; /"
            $data['country']           =$contacts_details->country_id;/"
            $data['city']              =$contacts_details->city;/"
            $data['contact_mobile']    =$contacts_details->contact_mobile;
            $data['unique_id']         =$contacts_details->unique_id;

            array_push($result, $data);
          }

          echo json_encode(array('data' => $result));
```

Comment: you are getting single or multiple result in $row ?

Comment: then you need to make for loop on result bcz its has multiple result

Comment: ok fine, its worked for me.My another question how can i render this  json data  in html elements.?

Answer (score 1):

Your `function get_all_contacts()` returns normal array and you are trying to execute it as stdClass object .

Make it `result()` and add it to loop or change `$contacts_details->contact_id;`

to the

`$contacts_details['contact_id]';` and please [refer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php).